# PayPal Payouts with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am trying to make payouts using the PayPal API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/api-integration/).

I have my token.

Now I am creating my body:

```
body = {
         :sender_batch_header => {
             :sender_batch_id => SecureRandom.hex(8),
             :email_subject => 'You have a Payout!'
         },
         :items => [
             {
                 :recipient_type => 'EMAIL',
                 :amount => {
                     :value => '0.01',
                     :currency => 'EUR'
                 },
                 :note => 'Thanks for your patronage!',
                 :sender_item_id => '2014031400023',
                 :receiver => 'xxx@gmail.com'
             }
         ]
}
```

And make the request:

```
response = HTTParty.post("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts", :headers => { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}"}, :body => body)
```

But all I get is a generic response

> {"date":["Wed, 15 May 2019 02:28:21
>   GMT"],"server":["Apache"],"paypal-debug-id":["eacd2165b90d","eacd2165b90d"],"connection":["close"],"http_x_pp_az_locator":["sandbox.slc"],"set-cookie":["X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dapiplatformproxyserv%26TIME%3D1165613916%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc;
>   Expires=Wed, 15 May 2019 02:58:21 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/;
>   Secure; HttpOnly","X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01
>   GMT"],"vary":["Authorization"],"content-type":["text/plain;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1"]}

I think there is something wrong with my body. I tried sending `body.to_json` and I also tried to use `:data` instead of `:body` but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: What are you using for front end?